# Undefined Variable warning while reading data from mySql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I've found several Undefined variable posts here, but none of them was about this case.

this is a part of a php page:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblmembers";
$rst = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_errno());

if ( mysql_num_rows ( $rst ) >0) {
   while (true==($result = mysql_fetch_array($rst))) {
      foreach ( $result as $key => $val) {
         $$key = $val ;
      }
   }   
}
print $last_name;
```

I'm receiving a Undefined variable $last_name in Zend Studio.
How can I solve this problem.
last_name is a field in mySQL table.

Comment: can you show us the output of `show create table tblmembers`?

Comment: Please explain where your are parsing value to variable `print $last_name;`??

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm afraid I can't understand what you mean. To make it simpler, let's imagine that If I have three fields in my table (userID, first_name & last_name) and use **$sql=SELECT * From tblmembers WHERE userID=1"** to fetch data, **$$key=$val** creates three variables ($userID,$first_name & $last_name) and their values are the values in the table. Since then I can use `print "Hi $first_name";` which shows something like ** Hi Peter". The code works perfect. But zendStudio shows undefined variable.